# How to see the MongoDB has More Records

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection named logins  in my Mongo DB .
I want to see all the rows present in that collection , but after displaying 20 records , its displaying has more .

Please let me know , how can i see the remaining records ??

```
db.logins.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d779d36f282963924633b01"), "env_name" : "qa", "cust_id" : "kiran", "epoch" : "1299684662765", "created_at" : "2011-03-09 10:31:02.765" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d779db7f282963925633b01"), "env_name" : "qa", "cust_id" : "pavan", "epoch" : "1299684791157", "created_at" : "2011-03-09 10:33:11.157" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d779dcff282963926633b01"), "env_name" : "qa", "cust_id" : "hhhiuy", "epoch" : "1299684815595", "created_at" : "2011-03-09 10:33:35.595" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d779e26f282963927633b01"), "env_name" : "qa", "cust_id" : "testaccount", "epoch" : "1299684902416", "created_at" : "2011-03-09 10:35:02.416" }

------
------
------
has more
```

Thanks in advance .

How can i see the remaining records also ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just type `it` in the command prompt. I believe, this is short from "iterator" or something like that.